# Formatting of online help in PyCharm's python console

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm's python console, when one asks for the documentation of a function, it returns a dictionary that is not exactly easy to read. For example,

```
? os.path
```

would print

```
{'text/plain': "Type:        module\nString form: <module 'ntpath' from 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Bob\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Continuum\\\\Miniconda3\\\\envs\\\\bob\\\\lib\\\\ntpath.py'>\nFile:        c:\\users\\bob\\appdata\\local\\continuum\\miniconda3\\envs\\bob\\lib\\ntpath.py\nDocstring:  \nCommon pathname manipulations, WindowsNT/95 version.\n\nInstead of importing this module directly, import os and refer to this\nmodule as os.path.\n"}
```

Can PyCharm be configured to return a formatted version of this help, as within a standard IPython console?

The question could also be, how to get this formatted help from within the console in PyCharm. I know that a QuickHelp popup can be summoned by pressing Ctrl+Q on a function name lying in an opened file. However, as I debug in the console window, I don't want to modify my file and type a function name at a random location just to get help if possible.

Comment: Did you find any workaround or solution? This is really annoying.